# Filebeat is unable to connect to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, filebeat, elk

Filebeat is unable to connect to the elk. The filebeat log file shows the below error.

pipeline/output.go:154  Failed to connect to backoff(elasticsearch(http://X.X.X.X:9200)): Connection marked as failed because the onConnect callback failed: could not connect to a compatible version of Elasticsearch: 400 Bad Request: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"invalid_index_name_exception","reason":"Invalid index name [*license], must not start with '*'.","index_uuid":"*na*","index":"_license"}],"type":"invalid_index_name_exception","reason":"Invalid index name [*license], must not start with '*'.","index_uuid":"*na*","index":"_license"},"status":400}

filebeat version 7.13.2
elk version 7.5.1

Can somebody please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your version of ELK is open source then 7.13 Beats will not work with it due to a [breaking change](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/libbeat/current/breaking-changes-7.13.html#breaking-changes-7.13). From 7.13, Beats will only work with the Elastic distribution.

Comment: Thanks @aag6z. How to know which version of filebeats will work with open source ELK 7.5.1 ?

Comment: @ShivaPrasad I would try any Beats before 7.13. Based on this: https://www.elastic.co/support/matrix#matrix_compatibility they should work. It's just the licensing change that makes 7.13+ incompatible with OSS ELK.